# Having trouble correctly reading microphone input with pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to build a python program that plots the microphone input waveform in real time using the pyaudio library. I've only gotten far enough to where I am trying to plot one single instant of the waveform and I am running into a problem. Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CHUNK = 4096
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    output=True,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

stream.start_stream()
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
data_int = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
print(data_int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data_int, '-')
plt.show()
```

When I run this I do get a graph plotted but all of the values are either 1, 0, or -1 instead of being an audio wave. [Here is an image of the plot I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLG1l.png). This plot is exactly the same every time I run the program.

I am just using my laptop's built in microphone for this and have confirmed that it is working in other applications. Any ideas on what could be causing the audio input to not be read in correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but this [video](https://youtu.be/AShHJdSIxkY) seems to be pretty canny to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That is the video that I got most of this code from actually. The only thing I really changed from his code is not using the struct library and instead using np.frombuffer()

Comment: Interesting, I'll test it out on my system and get back to you.

Comment: I wouldnt know why, sorry. I would just use the struct package and modify it how the comments say.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same issue